# Preventing ClaimsTransformation from running on every HTTP request

Tags: iis, .net-core, asp.net-authorization

I have a web application targeting .NET 5.0 and I am trying to implement Windows Authentication along with some policies for authorization. We have a database table from another application that holds info on user roles, so I am using that to set permissions for my users.

I created a ClaimsTransformer class:

*ClaimsTransformer.cs*

```
public class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
{
    // snip constructor which pulls in my DbContext from DI

    public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        var id = ((ClaimsIdentity) principal.Identity);
        
        var ci = new ClaimsIdentity(id.Claims, id.AuthenticationType, id.NameClaimType, id.RoleClaimType);

        // snip call to DbContext to get user's role from database

        if (roleId == 1 || roleId == 7)
        {
            ci.AddClaim(new Claim("user-role", "admin"));
        }

        return new ClaimsPrincipal(ci);
    }
}
```

I have my authentication/authorization setup like this:

*Startup.cs*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy =>
            policy.RequireClaim("user-role", "admin"));
    });

    // snip rest of method
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // snip unrelated code
    
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
}
```

My first use of this is to hide a menu in my `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@if ((await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "admin").Succeeded)
{
    // Admin nav link
}
```

The issue is, since `AuthorizeAsync` is running on every HTTP request, my ClaimsTransformer also runs each time, hitting the database to check the user's roles on every request. I'd like to avoid this, but I'm not sure of the best way to do so.

Basically, I'd like the system to check the roles only once, when the user is first authenticated. I read that this is what is supposed to happen when using Windows Authentication with IIS, but I am seeing the roles query running on every request when deployed to my IIS server also.

I could easily add a check in my ClaimsTransformer to see if the "user-role" claim exists, and only hit the DB if it is not present, but is there a better way? Should I be overriding something like `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory` instead of using a ClaimsTransformer?

Comment: Why prevent ClaimsTransformation from running on every HTTP request? Is it because you think that every time you run ClaimsTransformer, it will operate the database and slow down the performance?

Comment: @DingPeng exactly...I'd like to avoid the multiple database hits, if possible...although, I'm not as upset by this as I was originally -- by not caching the authentication result, if a user's access is modified while they are using the system, the change will take effect immediately even if they are actively logged in. It also seems this is necessary, since with each request the custom claims I am adding disappear, so they need to be re-added on every request anyway...

Comment: I have a similar situation. what did you do to avoid multiple database hits?

Comment: I have the same case. Ideally roles should be fetched from DB once and then added to the Identity once upon authentication. This identity should be cached in cookie and transformation should not be fired on every request. Not sure how to achieve this.